# From latex to word through vector graphics

Tags: microsoft-word, conversion, latex, export, vector-graphics

Maybe what I say is crazy and nonsense, but this could be the right way to convert from LaTeX to word.

As you may have noticed, there are some conversors form LaTeX to word, correct me if wrong but none works quite well, specially when using equations and other features.

I thought about the most simple thing, probably. Just making screen captures of the PDF generated from LaTeX and inserting those in the word file. (something I did in powerpoint a few minutes ago inspired me). However images could be pixelated and in the end they don't look so well after a while.

Thus I thought of a slightly better solution, generating vector graphics out of the PDF and then putting those into the word file. That should look reasonably well, and should be fairly simple to implement. Is there any software to make it easier? Am I missing something? (For instance a LaTeX2Word program/plugin/service that does really work, or some reason why vector graphics would look horrible if I did what I suggest)

Thank you very much.

Comment: check this answer on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4123701/586014

Comment: There's not much point in having a Word document if every page is just a big picture.  It won't be editable, nor will the text be readable by software.  Might as well just stick with the PDF.

Comment: The margins could be still edited. Sometimes people don't need to edit some word document but just being able to merge it inside a greater word document that needs to be edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if Word can import PostScript graphics. If that's possible you can first divide the PDF into single pages:

```
pdftk <pdffile> burst
```

Then you convert each PDF page into Encapsulated PostScript:

```
for i in *.pdf; do pdftops -eps "$i";done
```

Another option is to use `inkscape` to convert the PDF to SVG. However, this might not always give best results:

```
for i in *.pdf; do inkscape -z -l="$i".svg "$i";don
```